# delete a multiple selected rows in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have numbers of rows in a grid. The first column is an checkbox. If I check that checkbox and click on delete button, the checked row should be delete. Incase If I check more than 10 rows randomly, the selected rows should be delete. How can I do this using jquery.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nMhmS/1285/)

Please look at this fiddle. Here, if I select 2nd and 5th row checkbox and if i press delete button, the 2nd and  5th row should be delete. It should happen dynamically not in static. As an example I have mension 2nd and 5th. If I select multiple checkbox in a table, need to delete all selected rows. Please help me how can I do this?

```css
#codexpl th, #codexpl td{
    padding:0.8em;
    border: 1px solid;
}
#codexpl th{
    background-color:#6699FF;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<br><br>
<input type="button" value ="Delete">
<table id="codexpl">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Columna</th>
        <th>Relative</th>
        <th>Isso</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>This</td>
        <td>Column</td>
        <td>Is</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Coloumn</td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td>this</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>is</td>
        <td>not equals</td>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>the</td>
        <td>Column</td>
        <td>real</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>first</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Coloumn</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `on` handler on `button` and use `:checked` selector to find checked elements.

[`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) will delete set of matched elements from `DOM`

Try this:

```js
$('[type="button"]').on('click', function() {
  $('td input:checked').closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```css
#codexpl th,
#codexpl td {
  padding: 0.8em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#codexpl th {
  background-color: #6699FF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Delete">
<table id="codexpl">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Columna</th>
    <th>Relative</th>
    <th>Isso</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Is</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>Coloumn</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>this</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>is</td>
    <td>not equals</td>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>the</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>real</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>first</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Coloumn</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/nMhmS/1286/)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Bind the click handler of `Delete` button using [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/), find the [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) checkbox then use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to traverse up to `tr` element, then use [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/).

For simplicity, I have added id to the button as `btnDelete`

```
$(function() {
  $('#btnDelete').on('click', function() {
    $('#codexpl :checkbox:checked').closest('tr').remove();
  });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btnDelete').on('click', function() {
    $('#codexpl :checkbox:checked').closest('tr').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
#codexpl th,
#codexpl td {
  padding: 0.8em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#codexpl th {
  background-color: #6699FF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" id="btnDelete" value="Delete">
<table id="codexpl">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Columna</th>
    <th>Relative</th>
    <th>Isso</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Is</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>Coloumn</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>this</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>is</td>
    <td>not equals</td>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>the</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>real</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>first</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Coloumn</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Register a click handler for delete button (assigne some id to button as shown below). Inside click handler, find all check boxes in table and call remove on parent tr using closest.

**Note**: Don't forget to include jQuery library file in your code.
e.g. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

HTML:`<input type="button" value="Delete" id="deleteBtn">`

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $("#deleteBtn").click(function() {
    $("#codexpl").find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").closest("tr").remove();
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/nMhmS/1287/)